# All-pay auction question

Tags: self-learning, game-theory, economics, auction-theory

Two players take part in the following auction for a £1000 prize. The two players submit bids simultaneously, and the higher bid wins the prize (if bids are identical each gets £500). Both the winner and the loser have to pay the seller the amount of their bids. The players can bid any nonnegative amount.

Find Nash equilibrium in pure strategies.

Find a mixed strategy equilibrium.

—-

** I start with finding Nash equilibrium **

Players ={P1, P2}

Valuation= 1000

Bids= {b1, b2} $\in [0, 1000]$

Payoffs are

$U_i(b1,b2)= 1000-b_i$ if $b_i>b_j$

$U_i(b1,b2)= 500-b_i$ if $b_i=b_j$

$U_i(b1,b2)=-b_i$ if $b_i<b_j$

Case 1: b1=b2

If b1=b2=1000, then $U_i(b1,b2)= 500-1000=-500$

There is a profitable deviation for players. For example P1 may deviate to b1=0. P1 loses, P2 wins. Both players have zero payoff. So, (1000,1000) is not Nash equilibrium.

If $b1=b2=0$, then $U_i(b1,b2)= 500-0=500$

There is a profitable deviation for players. For example P1 may deviate to b1=1. P2 loses, P2 loses. $U_1(b1,b2)=999$ and $U_2=0$. So, (0,0) is not Nash equilibrium.

If $0<b1=b2=<1000$, then one of the players has an incentive to bid higher than the another’s bid in order to increase her payoff. So, this case is also not Nash equilibrium.

Case 2: $b1\not= b2$

If $b_i>1000$ then this player wins, but she gets negative payoff. So this is not logical.

If $0<b1\not= b2<1000$, then player with lower bid has an incentive to bid higher than the another’s bid in order to increase her payoff. So, this case is also not Nash equilibrium.

As a result, there is no Pure Nash equilibrium for this game.

** Next, I try to find mixed strategy Nash equilibrium. **

Assume that P1 bids $b1=b^*$

The expected payoff of P1 is as follows

$$=P(b_2<b^*)U_1(b_1,b_2)+ P(b_2=b^*)U_1(b_1,b_2)+ P(b_2>b^*)U_1(b_1,b_2)$$

$$= P(b_2<b^*)[1000-b^*]+ P(b_2=b^*)[500-b^*]+ P(b_2>b^*)[-b^*]$$

I cannot proceed the solution after this point. How can I find this mixed strategy Nash equilibrium?

And is the findings about the Pure Nash equilibrium correct?

Please share your ideas with me. Thank you.

This question is [dublicate](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52438/all-pay-auction-question) I asked on both websites because I cannot receive enough answer and attention to auction questions.

EDIT

The expected payoff of P1 is as follows

$$=P(b_2<b^*)U_1(b_1,b_2)+ P(b_2>b^*)U_1(b_1,b_2)$$

$$ P(b_2<b^*)[1000-b^*]+ P(b_2>b^*)[-b^*]=0$$

$$ P(b_2<b^*)[1000-b^*]-(1- P(b_2<b^*))b^*=0$$

$$ P(b_2<b^*)1000-b^*=0$$

$$ P(b_2<b^*)=b^*/1000$$

So, the probability of P2’s being loser is $b^*/1000$ This is mixed strategy Nash equilibrium.

Comment: You are correct about the Nash equilibrium in pure strategies. For the equilibrium in mixed strategies, I would suggest taking a look at the answer to this related question: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/24919/all-pay-auction-mixed-strategy-equilibrium. Since a budget constraint is not mentioned for the players in your version of the question, try seeing which terms drop out when you set the budget constraint to the size of the prize.

Comment: Dear @indnwkybrd thank you for your help. I improved my question according your suggestion and I  add my the last attempt to the question part. Please check for my answer. Thanks you so much.

Comment: I think you're almost there. The form of the equilibrium in mixed strategies would be a *probability distribution* over the set of possible bids, though. So what you want to show, is that if $b_i \sim \text{Uniform}[0, 1000]$ then both players would be indifferent across all bids. Check out the link (particularly the first equation after "Claim 2"), and keep in mind that in your case $t=1$; many terms will drop out, and then you just have to adjust things to multiply everything by $1000$.